# In-app Billing and subscriptions supported countries

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am presently in India. I want to integrate In-app and subscription billing to my app. Is it possible from my country??

Is Google market billing supported in India??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its not supported in India. Here is the list of countries supporting paid applications.

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324